# My program works in simulation but fails in game mode

Tags: screeps

I've set up my code so that my main module consists of only the following:

```
var main = require('main2');

main();
```

This works in simulation's survival training mode, where main is a function.  However, in the online survival mode I have started getting the following error:

```
main:3
main();
^
TypeError: object is not a function
    at main:3:1
    at process.emit (events.js:110:17)
```

Why have I started getting this error in the online survival mode?

Answer (score 3):

This has been just fixed. Now `require` should work correctly at server-side.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect that to invoke the function `main` in `main2`, you would use `main.main()`. var `main` is an object which contains the function `main`.

As to why it works in one context rather than the other, no idea. Perhaps you should ensure that the `require` is not actually returning empty/NULL/FILE NOT NOT FOUND. (should it be "./main2.js" etc.)